# Can I use a different transistor or mosfet?

Tags: amplifier

I want to make an amplifier for my speaker.

Here is the [link for the circuit.](https://www.hackster.io/dhritimanhb2015/how-to-make-simple-amplifier-circuit-without-ic-607c53)

[image]

Can I use a different transistor instead the 13007 MOSFET?

I have a LM35 transistor.

Comment: You can certainly use a different transistor, it would at least depend on the speaker you have, and the supply voltage you want to use. In order to get some help, you will need to add more details to the question.

Comment: The 13007 is a transistor and your LM35 is a temperature sensor ic. A mosfet is not a good choice for this application, so you need a transistor.

Comment: @Kartman thank you

Comment: https://www.hackster.io/dhritimanhb2015/simple-basic-audio-amplifier-with-bc547-amplifier-6bfc69

Comment: https://www.hackster.io/dhritimanhb2015/simple-basic-audio-amplifier-e086e3

Comment: 13007 on schematic is NPM transistor not MOSFET. By the way - Vce of 13007 is 400V but on schematic it is powered by only +9V - get any 4A NPM and you will be fine.

Comment: An "NPM" doesn't exist so forget that. A MOSFET **is** also a transistor. An LM35 is a temperature sensor IC and not a single transistor. A 13007 is **not** a MOSFET but an **NPN Power transistor**. Do realize that this is a **very crappy circuit** so do not expect too much from it! If you want a proper amplifier, get an "LM386 module". My advice: this circuit is too simple to be useful, don't spend any effort in making it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie do you realy think that I was written NPM deliberately and at the same time I know what Vce is? I am just not able to edit my comments.

Comment: _”I have a LM35 transistor.”_ That’s not a transistor but a temperature measurement IC.

Comment: @ufok Tip: copy the text of your comment and add it as a new comment, then fix the typos, delete old comment. I knew the "NPM" was a typo but explained it to prevent confusing the OP, the comment wasn't targeted at you.

Comment: Even with a transistor instead ot an LM35, please don't have any high expectations for this circuit. It may sort-of work but it's a terrible circuit that may distort badly, and drain the 9V battery pretty fast, and your speaker won't work very well with so much DC across it.